# Process not running in background

Tags: php, process, background-process

```
<?php
 while(true)
    {
    set_time_limit(2);
    $reas ="wake up from sleep!!!!!!!!!! \n ";
    echo $reas;
    sleep(5);
   // $readlen = 0;
    }
?>
```

I try to run this code. In foreground, it runs perfectly. But when run it in background and check the process, the id is not found. I've tried to use the `top` command to check and

```
  nohup php p2.php &
```

to get the process id, but when I try to kill the process using

```
 kill 1234
```

I get a error message "no such process".

What is wrong in my code? How do I run it in background and make it display in `top`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `screen` for that:

```
screen watch -n 1 ls -l /etc/
```

Then inside `screen` type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd> to detach the screen.

The process is still running, even if you logout, see:

```
# ps faux | grep ls
root     13879  0.0  0.0   7828   844 pts/0    S+   08:20   0:00          \_ grep ls
root     13571  0.0  0.0  23388  1436 ?        Ss   08:18   0:00 SCREEN watch -n 1 ls -l /etc/
root     13572  0.1  0.0  14864  1780 pts/1    Ss+  08:18   0:00  \_ watch -n 1 ls -l /etc/
```

And there is also the pid. Or via:

```
#pidof watch
13572
```

To reattch the screen type:

```
screen -r
```

And you are back inside, to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd> or something else.